# Need to access REST API from PowerBI after authentication

Tags: api, powerbi, informatica

I am trying to access Informatica Axon API from PowerBI, but it's not working.

The API needs to get authenticated in order to get accessed. I gave authorization details as below, but it's throwing an error.

**API details**
URL:

Authorization: Bearer XXXX

ContentType: application/json

**The error message:**

Web.Contents failed to get contents from "http://XXXX/unison/v1/facet/_search (405): Method Not Allowed".

The same details are working in Postman.

Can you please advise me?

Thanks.

Comment: Just make sure that you are using the same type of request on postman and in your code. Like if GET or POST it should be the same.

Comment: Thanks, Nayan. But I don't see GET or POST to select in PowerBI. There are 2 options in PowerBI web - 'Basic' and 'Advanced'. We just have to provide the URL in 'Basic' and we have to provide URL and Header details in 'Advanced'. So, I selected 'Advanced' and provided all the details.

Comment: What you selected in postman then. Because I think postman need a request type. Can you share what works on postman if possible

Comment: I selected POST in postman and it worked.

Comment: Thanks, Nayan. But PowerBI --> API is not working and I don't see anything to select POST method in PowerBI.